# Making many If statments into One statement. Php

Tags: php, if-statement

```
function rawtransform{

            if ($raw>=500 && $raw<=550){
                    $score= 1;
            }
            if ($raw>=550 && $raw<=600){
                    $score= 2;
            }
            if ($raw>=600 && $raw<=650){
                    $score= 3;
            }
            if ($raw>=700 && $raw<=750){
                    $score= 4;
            }
            if ($raw>=750 && $raw<=800){
                    $score= 5;
            }
            if ($raw>=800 && $raw<=850){
                    $score= 6;
            }
            if ($raw>=850 && $raw<=900){
                    $score= 7;
            }
            if ($raw>=900 && $raw<=950){
                    $score= 8;
            }
            if ($raw>=950 && $raw<=1000){
                    $score= 9;
            }
    }
```

This seems very basic and not very well coded. (I am only learning php )
Can anyone offer a better way of doing this? maybe a single if statement.  I think there is a way just cant get my head round it.

Thanks

Comment: Just some math. Whenever you add 50, score increases by one.

Comment: Also check the syntax, in PHP a function name is usually followed by parentheses containing the parameters.

Comment: If `$raw` is 550, what is `$score`? 1 or 2? The pseudo-code above will first set it to 1 than to 2. What should actually happen, does the sequence in setting the variable is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using math?

```
function rawtransform($raw) {
  $score = (int)($raw/50)-9;
}
```

You may want to add a range check for the input, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of conditions, and loop through the and apply the if.

```
$conditions = array(
    array(500, 550, 1), // greater than value, lesser than value, assignment value
    array(550, 600, 2),
    array(650, 700, 3)  // add the rest of the conditions
);

foreach($conditions as $condition) {
    if($raw >= $condition[0] && $raw <= $condition[1]) {
        $score = $condition[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($raw >= 500 && $raw<= 1000){
        $score = ceil(($raw-500)/50);
}
```

Comment: If by faster you mean "academically faster" and not "really faster" :) .. it's a microoptimization afaik, not worth the effort

Comment: It wasn't me, but I suspect because it isn't an answer to the question: it might be an ever so slightly faster code, but certainly not cleaner/better/clearer then the one in the question? Edit: ah, you've edited your answer now I see, but the downvote was probably for the previous one :)

Comment: @Nanne, that's why seconds later i added that extra answer.

Comment: Sure, I just tried to explain why you might have gotten a down vote. As said, it wasn't me.

Comment: @Nanne, I was just frustrated because my answer (using ceil() instead of floor()) was the only one working and was the one down voted. Welcome to SO.

Comment: You obviously got the downvote for your first try, that was still there after you asked about the downvote. Not really sure what the issue is here though, welcome to SO to you, and a good day.....

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be that you are subtracting 450 from raw, then dividing it by 50 and rounding down to the nearest whole number. (There are problems in your implementation however, as if raw is a factor of 50, it will meet the requirements for two of the if statements and there is a condition missing for when it falls between 650 and 700.)

You could do this as follows:

```
floor(($raw-450)/50)
```

Comment: Doesn't work with floor(). $raw = 555 will give $score = 1 instead of 2. -.-

Comment: Corrected logic, should have been -450. However, this still works differently than some of the if statements in his example code as I believe some are missing. In particular an if statement for 650-700.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if...else constructs.

```
        if ($raw>=500 && $raw<=550){
                $score= 1;
        }
        elseif ($raw>=550 && $raw<=600){
                $score= 2;
        }
        elseif ($raw>=600 && $raw<=650){
                $score= 3;
        }
```

That way, if the script encounters a size of, say, 575 it won't even bother to go through the following conditions.

In your given example, the script can be simplified by:

```
function rawtransform($raw) { $score = floor(($raw - 450)/50); return $score; }
```

Comment: the latest function does nothing... it stores a local variable and then return nothing...

Comment: The code doesn't work anyway. $raw = 555 will give 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli The original function in question was even worse. My answer was just to show how the whole if construct could be simplified. Edited the function now to work properly.